# Issue with Posting JSON data with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, post

I am facing a specific issue with making a post call using `Angular js`, the below code fails with error:

> Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

How ever if I make the same call by passing parameters in plain text format, by appending values directly in URL it works. Any help here is appreciated.

eg: `https://sample.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/authenticate/login?username=rakesh&password=somepassword`

```
angular.module("sampleApp2",[])
.service("apiCalls",function($http) {

    var result;

    var postdata = {username: "rakesh", Password: "somepassword"} ;

    this.cobLogin = function(callback,errcallback) {

            result = $http({
            method:'POST',
            data:postdata,
            url:'https://sample.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/authenticate/login'

        }).then(callback, errcallback);
}
return result;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using the wrong content type. The default is `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You want `Content-type: application/json`. You can set this in the headers option. Check the [$http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

```
var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://example.com',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 },
 data: { test: 'test' }
}

$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide headers

```
angular.module("sampleApp2",[])
.service("apiCalls",function($http) {

    var result;

    var postdata = {username: "rakesh", Password: "somepassword"} ;

    this.cobLogin = function(callback,errcallback) {

            result = $http({
            method:'POST',
            url:'https://sample.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/authenticate/login',
            data:postdata,
            headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/json'}


        }).then(callback, errcallback);
}
return result;
});
```